# My Sound Card Stopped Working - Message: Dummy Output

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and suddenly my sound stopped working! When I go to sound settings appears that my sound card is a dummy output - just like that! Use a Dell Latitude 3440 without HDMI and Nvidia video card, which could be the case of problems too
Do sound tests and nothing happens!

The only thing I did differently was to use a 4G modem. Is he wrong? Some kind of conflict?

Already performed several steps to address this problem including this [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) and to no avail.

When I try to run the "alsamixer" says the directory is invalid! But I could run the following command and analyze the parameters: sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf - but the mixer command does not work!

I believe that I should reinstall the sound card but I can not do this procedure! Can anyone help me?

**EDITED:** My lspci -v output (I dont see my pci sound card!):

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0606
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Capabilities:
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0607
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 58
>       Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
>       Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>       I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
>       Expansion ROM at  [disabled]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: i915
>
> 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0606
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
>       Memory at f7a05000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: mei_me
>
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
>       I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
>       Memory behind bridge: cf200000-cf3fffff
>       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000cf400000-00000000cf5fffff
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>
> 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
>       Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>
> 00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
>       I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
>       Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>
> 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
>       Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
>       I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
>       Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
>       Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: pcieport
>
> 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0606
>       Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
>       Memory at f7a03000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0606
>       Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
>
> 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0606
>       Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 56
>       I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
>       I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
>       I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
>       I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
>       I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
>       Memory at f7a02000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: ahci
>
> 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0606
>       Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 5
>       Memory at f7a01000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
>       I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
>
> 06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 020c
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
>       Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
>       Expansion ROM at f7980000 [disabled] [size=64K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: ath9k
>
> 07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0606
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 57
>       I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
>       Memory at f7804000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
>       Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: r8169
>
> 08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
>       Subsystem: Dell Device 0607
>       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 59
>       Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
>       Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>       Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
>       I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
>       Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: nouveau

**EDITED**: After I run de command line:

> wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh

**Result:**

> upload=true&script=true&cardinfo= !!################################
>   !!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64 !!################################
>
> !!Script ran on: Sun Nov 30 08:27:33 UTC 2014
>
> !!Linux Distribution !!------------------
>
> Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu
>   14.04.1 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS" HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
>   SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
>   BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
>
> !!DMI Information !!---------------
>
> Manufacturer:      Dell Inc. Product Name:      Latitude 3440 Product
>   Version:   Not Specified Firmware Version:  A09
>
> !!Kernel Information !!------------------
>
> Kernel release:    3.13.0-40-generic Operating System:  GNU/Linux
>   Architecture:      x86_64 Processor:         x86_64 SMP Enabled:
>   Yes
>
> !!ALSA Version !!------------
>
> Driver version:      Library version:    1.0.27.2 Utilities version: 
>   1.0.27.2
>
> !!Loaded ALSA modules !!-------------------
>
> !!Sound Servers on this system !!----------------------------
>
> Pulseaudio:
>         Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
>         Running - Yes
>
> !!Soundcards recognised by ALSA !!-----------------------------
>
> !!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
>   !!--------------------------------------
>
> !!Advanced information - PCI Vendor/Device/Subsystem ID's
>   !!-------------------------------------------------------
>
> !!Modprobe options (Sound related) !!--------------------------------
>
> snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2 snd_intel8x0m: index=-2 snd_via82xx_modem:
>   index=-2 snd_usb_audio: index=-2 snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
>   snd_usb_ua101: index=-2 snd_usb_us122l: index=-2 snd_usb_usx2y:
>   index=-2 snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388 snd_pcsp: index=-2
>   snd_usb_audio: index=-2
>
> !!Loaded sound module options !!---------------------------
>
> !!ALSA Device nodes !!-----------------
>
> crw-rw---- 1 root audio 116,  1 Nov 29 21:55 /dev/snd/seq crw-rw---- 1
>   root audio 116, 33 Nov 29 21:55 /dev/snd/timer
>
> !!Aplay/Arecord output !!--------------------
>
> APLAY
>
> aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
>
> ARECORD
>
> arecord: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
>
> !!Amixer output !!-------------
>
> !!Alsactl output !!--------------
>
> --startcollapse--
>   --endcollapse--
>
> !!All Loaded Modules !!------------------
>
> Module ctr ccm bbswitch rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc uvcvideo
>   videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev nvidia
>   dell_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi dell_laptop dcdbas intel_rapl
>   x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm arc4
>   crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel
>   aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd ath9k joydev
>   ath9k_common ath9k_hw serio_raw lpc_ich ath ath3k btusb bluetooth
>   mac80211 cfg80211 mei_me mei wmi mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport
>   i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit ahci drm_kms_helper r8169 libahci drm mii
>   video
>
> !!ALSA/HDA dmesg !!--------------

Regards!
Giba

Comment: Install "pavucontrol" and look in "output devices" tab if you have a real  soundcard  : clic "set as default" button near it.

Comment: laugeo in "pavucontrol" don't show my sound card! For example when I select "Hardware Output Devices" nothing is showing! Tks!

Comment: No soundcard detected : first try ubuntu update. If not better, you can try  like http://askubuntu.com/questions/551689/creative-speakers-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/551858#551858  , after the EDIT

Comment: Thanks but dont work yet!

Comment: do you have sound booting from install cdrom?

Comment: what is `aplay -l` result booting normally?

Comment: The result of 'aplay -l' is aplay: device_list:268: nenhuma placa de som encontrada...

Comment: In the "sound trouble shooting" page  , did you do 1c ?

Comment: yes but dont work yet!