# Dummy Output, Built In Sound Card Not Detected, also Manufacture Hide Advanced Tab BIOS

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I am new on Linux, running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS without other OS. I found out that my output audio is dummy and no analog sound card had found. I'm not sure what is the cause. These are command output :

```
$ alsamixer
```

[image]

```
$ pavucontrol
```

[image]

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 3198
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at a1110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-30-generic
```

```
$ sudo lshw
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0e.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:a1110000-a1113fff memory:a1000000-a10fffff
```

```
$ sudo lshw  -class  audio
  *-multimedia              
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: e
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0e.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:a1110000-a1113fff memory:a1000000-a10fffff
  *-usb:1
       description: Video
       product: USB Camera
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       version: 0.01
       serial: 200901010001
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

I have tried :

- [Sound card not detected 16.04 Dell Inspiron 15 7579 (Dummy Output)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855587/sound-card-not-detected-16-04-dell-inspiron-15-7579-dummy-output)
- [Sound card not detected (Dummy Output only) on Dell XPS 13 9350](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180851/sound-card-not-detected-dummy-output-only-on-dell-xps-13-9350)
- [Dummy output for sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332456/dummy-output-for-sound)
- [My Sound Card Stopped Working - Message: Dummy Output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553559/my-sound-card-stopped-working-message-dummy-output)

...and other suggestions that I had found and I even couldn't remember the links, but still not works.

Also I couldn't access Advanced Tab on BIOS to see if my sound card had been disable accidentally since manufacture hide/ disable it.

Please kindly help me.

Your answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Access to the BIOS is a hardware issue and not related to Ubuntu or to any OS for that matter. See the manufactures documentation for your PC or contact their support.

Comment: Look at `sudo lshw  --class  audio` and find your sound in system startup logs `sudo journalctl  -b 0`

Comment: @waltinator there's statement with red colour said : x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS. Is it the problem?

Comment: @David I have contact them to check sound card availabity but they say unfortunately couldn't unhide Advanced Tab on BIOS :(

Comment: Therefore its not a problem but the way it works.

Comment: @David So what should I do to fix this issue please?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  You may click on any of these [edit] links to [edit] your question.

Comment: @waltinator Noted. So related to your code, what should I put attention and what should I do to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: So, after not following any of my suggestions, you now want more suggestions?

Comment: @waltinator I do following your suggestions. Result of cod $sudo lshw  --class  audio I had put on edited question and for $sudo journalctl - b 0 there're long logs that I couldn't understand, that's why later I'm asking you what kind of logs that I must put attention since I'm new on Linux.

Comment: I should have suggested ` sudo lshw --class sound` As for the log entries, they are to be read one-by-one. You can see how your system discovers the current system hardware, including your sound hardware.

Comment: @waltinator thank you for your swift response, but I still don't know how to fix my issue

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1235880/1004020

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Xubuntu 23.04 on my Minis Forum GK41.
I've try a lot of solution for a day and finally resolved wit this link: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

Basically you need to edit two files like explained in the **second part** of the guide.

1. Edit */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf* as root and add options `snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` at the end of this file.
2. Edit */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf* as root and add blacklist `snd_soc_skl` at the end of the file.
3. After making these changes, reboot your system.

To be precise now the Audio Output works with HDMI, still can't use my audio jack, but hey... that was what I need!

Regards